# Unsuccessful in converting byte array(of jpg file sent over socket through android client) back in to jpg file(file gets corrupt)

Tags: java, python, android, arrays, file

First, I get the Uri of the file I want to send. I know the Uri is correct because I was successful in converting the Uri to Bitmap and display it.
Next, I convert the Uri to an inputStream using the code:-

```
public InputStream uriToStream(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    return is;
}
```

Next, I convert the inputStream to byte array(byte[]) using the code:-

```
public byte[] streamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    int nRead;
    byte[] by = new byte[16384];
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((nRead = is.read(by, 0, by.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(by, 0, nRead);
    }

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Next, I used this code to establish a connection with the server and send data

```java
public class threadClient extends Thread {

    byte[] ByteFile;

    threadClient(byte[] byteFile) {
        ByteFile = byteFile;
    }

    public void run()  {
        try {
            Log.i("network","connecting....");
            Socket client = new Socket("192.168.0.120",6666);

            Log.i("network","connected");
            Log.i("network","sending data");
            DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            stream.writeInt(ByteFile.length);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            stream.write(ByteFile);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Log.i("network","data sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("network",e.toString());
        }
    }
  }
```

The server is running python. After the server accepts the connection from the client the server uses the following code to handle the client

```py
    def client_handler(client,address):
    
        print(f"Accepted connection")
    
        size = int(jpysocket.jpydecode(client.recv(1024)))
        print(f"file size = {str(size)}")
        with open("test.pdf","wb") as file:
            file.write(client.recv(size))
        print("file saved")
```

first, the server receives the size of the file, and then it receives the byte array and writes the file.

But surprise the file is corrupt......

PLEASE CAN SOMEONE HELP......

THANKYOU

Comment: `stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        stream.write(ByteFile);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();` If you close a stream you cannot write any more of course.

Comment: Further: it makes no sense to put the whole file in a byte array first. Do away with that array. Just read from the inputstream as you do now and directly write to the data outputstream.

Comment: `first the server receives the size of the file` That is very ok.  `and the it creates a byte array of that size and receives the byte array of the file from the client and writes that byte array into a file.` That makes no sense. Do not create a byte array to hold all the bytes of the file. Just write the received bytes directly to file.

Comment: Okk @blackapps I will give that a try

Comment: Sorry by mistake I wrote that the server first creates the byte array actually the server is directly writing the bytes into the file

Comment: `But surprise the file is corrupt......` I think the file size is less then the original file. Check that firs!

Comment: `size = int(jpysocket.jpydecode(client.recv(1024)))
        print(f"file size = {str(size)}")
        with open("test.pdf","wb") as file:
            file.write(client.recv(size))` Sorry. I do not know python and do not understand that code. It looks as if you only once read and save 1024 bytes. Where is the loop? Is the resulting file size 1024?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are filing byte array more than image's bytes.
for example if the image's byte's lengths is 1024, you are initializing byteArray with 16384 size, the byte become [1,2,3,4, 0, 0, 0, 0, //more zero till the end of byte array's size]
// 1,2,3,4 is your bytes and 0 are unused bytes

try to initialize byteArray with size of image's byte's lengths to get the correct result.

Comment: `public byte[] streamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException { int nRead;
        byte[] by = new byte[is.available()];
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((nRead = is.read(by, 0, by.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(by, 0, nRead);
        }

        return buffer.toByteArray();
    }` i changed the code that converts stream to byte array into this still no improvement

Comment: Of course not. There was nothing wrong with that piece of code.

Comment: I told you: you close() the stream an then try to write().